# Probelm in facing about Structure Types in c

Tags: c, function, types, structure

i'm currently working on Structure Types in my examples i'm working on I've currently made

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
int day, month, year;
} Date;

typedef struct {
char customer_name[1000]; //Name of the customer placing the order
int order_number; //The order number
Date order_date; //The date on which the order was placed
double total_price;
} Order;

/* print_order(the_order)
Given an Order object, print the order's details in the same format
described in the section above.
*/

void print_order(Order the_order){
printf("Order %d: Placed by %s on %d/%d/%d (price: $%f)\n",the_order.order_number, 
the_order.customer_name, the_order.order_date.month, the_order.order_date.day, 
the_order.order_date.year, the_order.total_price);
}

int main(){

//Create an order with order number 111, placed on November 25, 2021
Order orderA = {111, 11, 25, 2021, "Rebecca Raspberry"};
strcpy(orderA.customer_name, "Rebecca Raspberry");
orderA.order_number = 111;
orderA.order_date.year = 2021;
orderA.order_date.month = 11;
orderA.order_date.day = 25;
orderA.total_price = 6.10;

//Make a second order, this time with order number 116, placed on November 29, 2021
//This order is created using the { } initializer syntax. Notice the nested initializer
//for the date.
Order orderB = { "Fiona Framboise", 116, { 29, 11, 2021 }, 17.0 };

print_order(orderA);
print_order(orderB);

printf("Order %d: Placed by %s on %d/%d/%d (price: $%f)\n", orderA.order_number, 
orderA.customer_name, orderA.order_date.month, orderA.order_date.day, 
orderA.order_date.year, orderA.total_price); 

return 0;
}
```

I've wanted to know what does print_order(the_order) mean is it asking for a typedef of days, month and year? And for OrderB do i formatt them in the same way as the orderA or is this wrong? The output that i need is:

```
Order 111: Placed by Rebecca Raspberry on 11/25/2021 (price: $6.10)
Order 116: Placed by Fiona Framboise on 11/29/2021 (price: $17.00)
```

Would appericate a reposnse/help :)

Comment: If you remove the `printf` from `main` and change the format from `%f` to `%.2f` in `print_order` it seems to give the output you're looking for. I'm not sure what you're actually asking though. `print_order` receives a copy of an `Order` struct and prints it out.

Comment: Is it possible you can show me?

Answer (score 0):

1. `void print_order(Order the_order)` means `print_order` expects copy (value) of the type `Order` which is struct with 4 members (pointer, int, struct with 3 ints, and a double).  Usually, you pass structured by address to avoid copying large structs.
2. You both initialize and assign values to `orderA` which is confusing.  The order of initialization (of `orderA`) must match the order of the struct:

```
Order orderA = { "Rebecca Raspberry", 111, { 11, 25, 2021 }};
```

or use a designator list in which case you can choose the order:

```
Order orderA = { .customer_name = "Rebecca Raspberry", .order_number = 111, .order_date = { 11, 25, 2021 }};
```

Note: total_price is not initialized, but do you do assign it the value `6.10`.  `orderB` is correct.  @RetiredNinja already told you how to fix the format string:

```
void print_order(Order the_order){
    printf("Order %d: Placed by %s on %d/%d/%d (price: $%.2f)\n",the_order.order_number, 
        the_order.customer_name, the_order.order_date.month, the_order.order_date.day, 
        the_order.order_date.year, the_order.total_price);
}
```

I don't know why you print `orderA` twice both using `print_order()` and `printf` statement in `main()`.

Your code is formatted unconventionally (i.e. poorly) which makes it hard to reader: